# Hibernate - Edit code generated by hbm2ddl.auto property

Tags: hibernate, hbm2ddl, dashdb

Is there any way to edit the code generated by the tool hbm2ddl.auto from Hibernate? I ask this because I would like to insert the words `ORGANIZE BY ROW` in the `CREATE TABLE` statements generated by hibernate tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indirect method - u can write some code to have Hibernate write out the DDL's in a file (http://jandrewthompson.blogspot.in/2009/10/how-to-generate-ddl-scripts-from.html) . You then edit the file by hand and add the 'organize_by_row' clause to the create table DDL. Now run this file on column oriented dashDB/DB2

Comment: Thanks Mario. This will help so much. :D